# Uninstalling Vim compiled from source

Tags: vim

I compiled and installed vim according to these instructions
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

But After installing I deleted the source directory 
So,How do I uninstall vim now ?

I am using Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Why can't you extract the source again from the download?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-ie-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-lin

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To uninstall vim, you can just download again the sources and run in the source directory :

```
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim/vim73
sudo make uninstall
```

replacing `/usr/share/vim/vim73` by the one you used for installation.

Comment: i did just that .But it didn't remove vim .I can still use vim.Here is the output when i run sudo make uninstall http://paste.ubuntu.com/5903278/

Comment: @ka4tik indeed, you need to set again the `VIMRUNTIMEDIR` variable. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: that did't work either http://paste.ubuntu.com/5903309/

Comment: @ka4tik and if you run all the same steps as for installation, by replacing `make install` by `make uninstall`, and also not using `sudo` for `make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=...`, as in the doc you supplied ?

Comment: Also works for Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

You have to run `make distclean` before `make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=...`

```
cd ~/tmp
hub clone vim/vim
cd vim
make distclean <---
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim80
sudo make uninstall
```