# Downgrading from Vim 8.1 to Vim 7.4 in (L)Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu-14.04, version, lubuntu

I firstly installed Vim in my (L)Ubuntu 14.04 with sudo apt-get install vim After that, as required from a plugin I wanted to use, I upgraded to Vim 8.1 using the ppa:jonathonf/vim repository. Being disappointed by that plugin I wanted to try another one but it has a still unsolved bug in Vim 8.1, this is why I now need to downgrade to Vim 7.4. My idea is to completely uninstall Vim and then reinstall it (having already removed ppa:jonathonf/vim).

To do so I tried

```
    sudo apt-get purge vim
```

and

```
    sudo apt-get autoremove
```

a couple of times and now I get this:

```
    user@computerName:~$ sudo apt-get purge vim
    [sudo] password for user: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Package 'vim' is not installed, so not removed
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

However, Vim is still there and I can use it. If I check for Vim version within Vim I get this:

```
    :ve
    VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled May 15 2019 14:58:47)
```

Perhaps there is an easier way to downgrade a software in Linux? Or is my idea valid? Do you have any suggestion? Thank you!

PS: As advised by GiftZwergrapper:

```
    user@computerName:~$ which vim
    /usr/bin/vim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing `vim` (`sudo apt-get remove vim`), check where the current `vim` is pointing to, e.g.

```
$ which -a vim # List all vim binaries.
/usr/bin/vim
$ stat $(which vim) # Same as: stat /usr/bin/vim
  File: /usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
$ ls -la $(which vim) # Same as: ls -al /usr/bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec  9 03:18 /usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
$ ls -la /etc/alternatives/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 May 18 14:49 /etc/alternatives/vim -> /usr/bin/nvim
```

If it's a symbolic link, find the path to the end binary, and check to which package it belongs to:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/nvim
neovim: /usr/bin/nvim
```

In my case, I had also Neo Vim installed, so I had to remove it as well:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove neovim
...
Removing neovim (0.3.1-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.tiny to provide /usr/bin/ex (ex) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.tiny to provide /usr/bin/rview (rview) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.tiny to provide /usr/bin/vi (vi) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.tiny to provide /usr/bin/view (view) in auto mode
$ vim
Command 'vim' not found.
```

---

To downgrade, change the version of Vim, try the following methods.

1. Find the available Vim package via `apt-cache search ^vim`.
2. Find the available version of the package: `apt-cache madison vim`.
3. Install the available version by: `sudo apt-get install vim=2:8.0\*`.

   See: [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92019/78223)

From what I've seen, there is no older version than 8.0 available in the Apt repository. You can try to find alternative Vim repository and add it using `add-apt-repository` command. But installing it from untrusted 3rd party sources could be a risk.

For older releases, you can also check [Vim Releases at GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases). Since there are not packages available, you probably need to compile it from the source (see: [Building Vim from source](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source). To uninstall, see: [Uninstalling Vim compiled from source](https://superuser.com/q/623040/87805).